# Is it neccessary to call the pthread_mutex_destroy when free a struct memory which contains a pthread_mutex_t

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Let's say I have a sruct:

```
typedef struct peer_info {
        int ip;
        int port;
        int offset;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} peer_info;
```

and then I use the struct and free the struct like below:

```
peer_info* p_info = (peer_info*)malloc(sizeof(peer_info));
pthread_mutex_init(&p_info->mutex, NULL);

/* do some work on the p_info */


// need I call the pthread_mutex_destory(&p_info->mutex); ?
free(p_info);
```

I checke the glibc ntpl souce code, it seems i don't need to explictly call `pthread_mutex_destory()` since there is not memroy allocted on the `pthread_mutex_t`, which is a union type.

Comment: What happens if `pthread_mutex_init` does some dynamic allocation or otherwise creates or allocates a resource of some kind? How would that resource become unallocated or destroyed if you don't call `pthread_mutex_destory`? Just because one very specific implementation doesn't do it, doesn't mean all implementations will work the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude dude, it does not allocate memory. Check https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_mutex_init.c.html

Comment: Again, a single specific implementation does not mean all implementations work the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Let's assume it does not allocate the memory, is it safe not call the pthread_mutex_destory()?

Comment: I still would call it. Why is it a problem to have such a call? What problem would removing that call solve? This seems like too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Re "*Let's assume it does not allocate the memory*", That would not make it safe. It could allocate other kinds of resources. Other mutex operations could still allocate memory or other kinds of resources.

Comment: Why even ask the question? What advantage is realistically to be gained by performing half-assed resource cleanup where you could just as easily do it right?  And don't tell me "performance" unless you can point to a profiling analysis that shows the `pthread_mutex_destroy` calls you imagine avoiding to be responsible for a non-trivial proportion of your program's running time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you've initialised the mutex with `pthread_mutex_init()`, it should be destroyed with `pthread_mutex_destroy()` before freeing the memory.

The POSIX standard contemplates both implementations where the mutex entirely resides in the `pthread_mutex_t` type, and implementations where the type includes only a reference to some externally-allocated mutex object.  This is reinforced by the fact that `pthread_mutex_init()` is allowed to fail due to various resource-exhaustion reasons.

Calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()` where appropriate ensures your code is portable to the latter kinds of implementations.

Comment: Thanks caf,  **and implementations where the type includes only a reference to some externally-allocated mutex object** which will allocate some memory and pointer to it? So we have to call `pthread_mutex_destory()` explicitly?

Comment: @SeanKuo: Yes.  Or it might allocate a kernel-level object instead of memory - the same applies, you must call `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer on Richard's APUE book.

> A mutex variable is represented by the pthread_mutex_t data type. Before we
> can use a mutex variable, we must first initialize it by either setting it to the constant
> PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER (for statically allocated mutexes only) or calling
> pthread_mutex_init. If we allocate the mutex dynamically (by calling malloc, for
> example), then we need to call pthread_mutex_destroy before freeing the memory.